# Is it possible to add a log in xml file ? If yes, how?

Tags: xml, logging

Just wondering if I can place a logger like console.log , syso, printf etc on an xml file for example web.xml to check narrow down at which part of the compile log this xml is getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such mechanism.